# For loop in R to find expectation of N

Tags: r, loops

I just need help writing a for loop because I'm so new at this I literally can't get it to work. I understand the math and can get an answer for one iteration, but I need multiple (let's say 100 iterations).

What I'm trying to do:

1. Generate 10 random uniformly distributed numbers.
2. Take the cumulative product and define it to be N.
   So, N <- cumprod(U) and say that cumprod(U) >= exp(-3).
   It's either TRUE or FALSE for cumprod(U) being >= exp(-3) for each random number multiplied.
3. Perform sum(N) which returns how many TRUE values there were. This number tells me how many times we had to multiply the randomly generated numbers together before we got below the value exp(-3). If I do this many many times, I should find that the expected value for N is around 3.

When I run the code below I get one answer, which is fine and expected, but what I can't figure out how to do since I'm not good at coding is how to get this code below to repeat itself 100 times (or 200 or 300, or whatever I choose). Can someone please help?

```
U <- runif(10)
N <- cumprod(U) >= exp(-3)
sum(N)
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need an explicit loop:

```
val <- exp(-3)
results <- replicate(100, sum(cumprod(runif(10)) >= val))
quantile(results)
table(results)
mean(results)
```

Comment: I appreciate your help very much, thank you!